# process.env on Client-Side ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I understand that process.env only work on server-side, I want to use the same concept but in client side because my app is deployed on aws s3, I know that we can put a variable in process.env from webpack how I can do the same but in client side?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you want to put in `process.env` variable. As you said, you can use webpack to provide this values. And they will be aviable on client-side. Why is it not enough?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `webpack.DefinePlugin` to put variables in `process.env`. Below, most common example with React:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      'NODE_ENV': '"production"'
    }
  })
]
```

isn't it enough?

---

I've created this example to prove that it works:

```
// webpack.config.js
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': '"production"'
            }
        })
    ]
};

// index.js
console.log(process.env);

console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
```

and the output file of this configuration is like this:

```
// ... some internal webpack init function ... 
([function(e,n){console.log(Object({NODE_ENV:"production"})),console.log("production")}]);
```

so as you may notice, values are replaced correctly.

If you need this variable you can do some initialization like:

```
global.myVar = process.env.NODE_ENV;
```

or something like this.

Comment: you can access the webpack variables from the client side?

Comment: What webpack does is replacing variables that it knows (in my example `process.env.NODE_ENV`) to it's value. So if you use this variable in your code and then this code is bundled with webpack it will be changed to the value which you provided in your webpack config.

Comment: I added example to my answer so it is clear how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using reactJs, and you wanna have this `global environment variable` you have some options:

1.- Create Global variables:
Is not my preferred choice, but all depends of what do you really need, If is something global that need be access from everywhere you can just:

```
window.process = {
   env: 'DEV',
   ....otherStuffs
}
```

2.- Use cookies or localstorage, if you just wanna save information, you can use local or session storage(all depends of the behaviour you expect), or even a cookie if you wanna have access from the server.

3.- My preferred, use `redux` then you can create a `global` reducer and include all the information that you need there, you will have to access to the state to get this information, but maybe this to overkill.

At the end, you have to analyze what works best for you.

Comment: I believe it's not a problem to set some global variables, the problem is to take an execution parameter or system global variable and set it within the application. Upon transpilation process in webpack - there is no access to `window` object and when the build is done you cannot get any environmental variable (as the build is a purely browser/client side).

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to use webpack.DefinePlugin, but before I could try that, I stumbled upon a straightforward solution. I wanted the client to make calls to my server on localhost if the env was "development" and make calls to the public IP (provided by AWS) if the env was "production". I was already using dotenv but for some reason, I couldn't make it work for my client.
I wrote a new script in package.json:

```
"build-prod": "webpack --mode production"
```

And then I added a .env file to my EC2 instance with NODE_ENV value of "production" and ran "npm run build-prod". So now on my client-side, wherever I had used "process.env.NODE_ENV", it would correctly refer to "production" and make the call to the correct IP address.